# How to get rid of device-camera entitlement warning?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a strange warning in my macOS app : `CMIO_DAL_PlugInManagement.cpp:191:Initialize Missing device-camera entitlement`

I am not doing anything with the camera. Basically my app is just showing a window with a SceneKit view and one object.

I tried adding the camera entitlement with value 'NO' with no luck.

How to get rid of that console warning ?

XCode 12.3, macOS BigSur

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide camera access to your macOS app

These permissions help to manage your application usage and save yourself from software exploits.

First, you need to enable camera capabilities in App Sandbox and Hardened runtime for your app.

[image: Enable Hardened runtime for your app]

[image: Enable Sandbox for your app]

After this you can add the key and value from the following document
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_device_camera

Hope this helps for you

Comment: Setting as you show indeed removes the warning, but allows to access camera and mike, which I don't need. So the question is "how to you tell you don't need the mike/camera and don't get a warning" ?